# I want to use checkboxes and sorting feature of the DataTable widget at the same time in flutter. I am only able to use any one

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, widget

I have created a data table with some modal data. Somehow, when sorting starts working checkboxes don't work and when checkboxes work sorting stops. I tried moving the generateRows() to build method, so checkboxes started working and sorting stopped. Please check the below given code why is that happening?

```
// This is the data modal class 
class DTOM {
  String name;
  int age;
  bool isSelected;
  DTOM({required this.name, required this.age, required this.isSelected});
}

List<DTOM> data = [
  DTOM(name: 'Rachna', age: 31, isSelected: false),
  DTOM(name: 'Siddhartha', age: 33, isSelected: true),
  DTOM(name: 'Vedika', age: 27, isSelected: false),
  DTOM(name: 'Vedant', age: 31, isSelected: true),
  DTOM(name: 'Kanti', age: 50, isSelected: false),
];

// And this is the widget code


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_data_table_widget/data_table_object_model.dart';

class AdvancedTable extends StatefulWidget {
  AdvancedTable({super.key});

  @override
  State<AdvancedTable> createState() => _AdvancedTableState();
}

class _AdvancedTableState extends State<AdvancedTable> {
  bool sortAscending = false;
  int sortColumnIndex = 0;
  List<DataRow> rows = [];
  generateRows() {
    return data.map(
      (e) {
        return DataRow(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          onSelectChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              e.isSelected = !e.isSelected;
            });
          },
          selected: e.isSelected,
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Text(e.name),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text(e.age.toString()),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rows = generateRows();
  }

  sortTable(columnIndex, ascending) {
    sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
    setState(() {
      if (ascending) {
        sortAscending = true;
        rows.sort((a, b) {
          return a.cells[columnIndex].child
              .toString()
              .compareTo(b.cells[columnIndex].child.toString());
        });
      } else {
        sortAscending = false;
        rows.sort((a, b) {
          return b.cells[columnIndex].child
              .toString()
              .compareTo(a.cells[columnIndex].child.toString());
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: DataTable(
            sortAscending: sortAscending,
            sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
            showCheckboxColumn: true,
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Name'),
                onSort: sortTable,
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Age'),
                onSort: sortTable,
              ),
            ],
            rows: rows,
          ),
        ),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens because you are creating the rows outside the `build` method and you only initialized them in `initState`. remember that when you sort the table, the rows list is being sorted, but the data modal is not getting updated, and `isSelected` of each item is being the same state. for fixing this problem please move `generateRows()` inside the `build` method

here is the updated code of you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_data_table_widget/data_table_object_model.dart';

class AdvancedTable extends StatefulWidget {
  AdvancedTable({super.key});

  @override
  State<AdvancedTable> createState() => _AdvancedTableState();
}

class _AdvancedTableState extends State<AdvancedTable> {
  bool sortAscending = false;
  int sortColumnIndex = 0;

  sortTable(columnIndex, ascending) {
    setState(() {
      sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      sortAscending = ascending;
      data.sort((a, b) {
        if (ascending) {
          return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
        } else {
          return b.name.compareTo(a.name);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: DataTable(
            sortAscending: sortAscending,
            sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
            showCheckboxColumn: true,
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Name'),
                onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) =>
                    sortTable(columnIndex, ascending),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Age'),
                onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) =>
                    sortTable(columnIndex, ascending),
              ),
            ],
            rows: data
                .map(
                  (e) => DataRow(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    onSelectChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        e.isSelected = !e.isSelected;
                      });
                    },
                    selected: e.isSelected,
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(
                        Text(e.name),
                      ),
                      DataCell(
                        Text(e.age.toString()),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

happy coding...

Comment: So concept is, whatever needs updating must be inside the build method Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! The build method is called by Flutter every time the state of a StatefulWidget changes or when the widget is first created.